# If there were elements on its scroll now

Tags: c#

How can I write code that?
If, for example, there was an element with the ID Reza browser scroll on it:

```
if ()
{
   webBrowser4.Document.GetElementById("ali").ScrollIntoView(true);
}
```

Comment: To what does your title refer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var element = webBrowser4.Document.GetElementById("ali");
if (element!=null)
{
   element.ScrollIntoView(true);
}
```